# Scale dynamic image with different widths and heights

Tags: css

I have image in the header and populate its source from the database, so it has different width and height. Image dimensions could be max 2000x2000px. I'm trying to scale it but when it's very large e.g more than 1000px it's very big and it's not looking good.
This is what I currently have.

```css
#image {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="some-dynamic-url" id="image">
</div>
```

I've also tried with `background-size: cover` but it's not stretched and how to preserve the aspect ratio and set `max-width` and `max-height` not to be so big?

Updated. My current code is the following:

```css
#image {
  display: block;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="some-dynamic-url" id="image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Will the height always be 50px?  If not, you should remove that from your CSS and instead use `height: auto;`.

Also, if it starts to not look so great at 1000px by 1000px, maybe set `width: 1000px;` and `max-width: 85%;` to keep it at that width and make it responsive on smaller screens. You can adjust the max-width value to your liking or remove it.

So, the CSS would change to:

```
#image {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 1000px;
  max-width: 85%; /* adjust as needed or remove */
  height: auto;
}
```

[Here's an example](https://codepen.io/VisualHarmony/pen/roZVMM).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you have a header container area where various images get populated, and sometimes the images are too big for the container and not looking good. (A screenshot would be helpful if my summary is wrong.)

The trick here is to set the image width to 100%, then set a max-width to either the image or the header container. (I picked 1200px for this example.) That ensures that your image will fill up all of the space, but not go over.

NOTE: this will cause images with widths smaller than 1200px to be stretched to fit, and may not look good either and would require some more coding to fix.

```css
#image {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/ESC_large_ISS022_ISS022-E-11387-edit_01.JPG" id="image">
</div>
```

However, if you're looking for a work-around for images that are smaller than 2000px wide, I'd suggest something like centering them with a colored background, or perhaps tiling them. Those solutions will be good for some content, and ugly for others - it depends what you images are like and how the site looks. But those are some ideas.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I tried this with setting `width` and `max-width` and it's  looking good  but what if the height is too big in that case? This image is just logo and should be kept in top left corner.

Comment: That depends on if your priority is to display the full image in the proper proportions OR fill up a certain amount of space with an image.

Comment: I personally never like to change the proportions of an image, so I almost always pull other levers to make them fit responsively into a page. Could you share a screenshot and some code of where you are now

Comment: So you could set any maximum height value with `max-height: 100px` , but that will likely cause the image to stretch or scrunch. But sometimes that doesn't look bad, and if not then I'd go with it.

Comment: If you don't like the stretch/scrunch, then consider using the image as a background to a div element that you put in its place. That would allow you to simply not show the extra height of the image without actually changing its dimensions.

Comment: I tried this using `background-image: cover` but it was cut, couldn't manage to show the whole image in it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the simple trick to automatically fit size with:

```
img { max-width: 1200px; height: auto;}
```

I guess 50px for height is not a must since you thought using "cover" in backround property. Also if you wish this sort of behavior from your image, you can add "object-fit: cover;".

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

EDIT

You can also use that version of the "trick":

```
img { max-height: 100px; width: auto; }
```

Note: Using files that big for logo is not recomand. If you got access tto database you should consider save a copy to more light version with less pixels.